How to mark a CI/CD child pipeline as passed when a new version has been deployed on later commit in GitLab?
I have a multiproject CI/CD pipeline in GitLab. Sometimes during a multiple child project deployment before I can deploy some subproject to production, a new version of that very subproject is deploy on a later commit. Then the deploy to production trigger button will show as blocked and the button becomes gray and unclickable. 
Since this subproject is not marked as passed, the parent project never passes.
My question is how should I config trigger-subprojects: section of my .gitlab-ci.yml file so when that happens, the pipeline passes and we know all subprojects are deploy on current or newer build?
Does this work as Git Copilot suggested:
trigger-subprojects:
  stage: triggers
  variables:
    UPSTREAM_PIPELINE_ID: $CI_PIPELINE_ID
  rules:
    - if: '$CI'
      when: always
  trigger:
    include:
      - artifact: generated-gitlab-ci.yml
        job: generate-yaml
    strategy: depend
  needs: [generate-yaml]
  script:
    - |
      if [ "$CI_JOB_STATUS" == "blocked" ]; then
        echo "Job is blocked, allowing failure."
        exit 0
      else
        echo "Job is not blocked, failing."
        exit 1
      fi


I have not used it but do any of the auto-cancel key words help here. https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#workflowauto_cancelon_new_commit
